# using "a/an" with "enjoyment"

Tags: word-usage

Can *enjoyment* be used with an article "a/an" or should it always be a non-countable noun?

For example,

> Listening to her was always an enjoyment.

[Among numerous examples of using "enjoyment" in sentences provided by Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/enjoyment) there is not one with "an".

Comment: was always enjoyable is better.

Comment: Or "was always a pleasure".

Comment: Your example is comprehensible, but not idiomatic. I would never use _an enjoyment_.

Comment: Always uncountable.  There's no enjoyment in it.  There's some enjoyment in it.

Answer (score -1):

Enjoyment is usually only used as a non-quantifiable noun, as seen in the examples on this webpage: https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/enjoyment
I would rephrase your example sentence to something like this:

> I listened to her for my own enjoyment.

...but it takes on a different meaning, so to keep the meaning it would be easier to change it to a more suitable word...

> Listening to her was always enjoyable.

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: @brilliant Your Collins example doesn't have any sentences with "a enjoyment". To use a similar word, "a fulfillment" is correct, so it shouldn't be any different than "an enjoyment". https://www.a-or-an.com/a_an/enjoyment

Comment: My question is not about whether it should be "is a enjoyment" or "is an enjoyment", but rather whether it should be "is enjoyment" or "is an enjoyment".